VS Code Snippet Confusing Transformation
I don't understand why this works:
"test": {
    "prefix": ".test",
    "body": [
    "${1/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}",
    "${2/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/};"
    ]
}

as opposed to below, which doesn't work, the 2nd tabstop gets cleared after you tab:
"test": {
    "prefix": ".test",
    "body": [
    "${1/(.*)/${1:/downcase}/}",
    "${2/(.*)/${2:/downcase}/};"
    ]
}

you'd expect in the first example that it would replace the 2nd tabstop with lowercase data from the 2nd but it makes the 2nd tabstop's data lowercase

it is the first group of the regex you apply to field 2
